# MYSQL LIKE CLAUSE ERROR

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form and through which i submit a input.

```
<form action= "index.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="input" required />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ask"/>
        </form>
```

in php

```
$input=$_POST['input'];
```

suppose i submitted `$input='IS BILL %'` i get error as

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS BILL % limit 1'

when i search for the input in a column of my table in a query..

```
$getdata= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aiml WHERE pattern like $input limit 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
if(!$getdata)
        echo "no data";
else
{
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata)) 
        {
                $text=$row['template'];
                echo $text;
         }
  }
```

but if in query i write
 `"SELECT * FROM aiml WHERE pattern like 'IS BILL %' limit 1 ") or die(mysql_error());`

i get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM aiml WHERE pattern like '%$input%' limit 1" // mathches the pattern containing $input

"SELECT * FROM aiml WHERE pattern like '$input%' limit 1" // mathches the pattern starting with $input

"SELECT * FROM aiml WHERE pattern like '%$input' limit 1" // mathches the pattern ending with $input
```

Answer (score 0):

In input text box just pass the query string means the word you want to search `IS BILL` 
not `IS BILL %`, Use `%` in SQL Query

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aiml WHERE pattern like '%".$input."%' limit 1 ")
```